# Why does my window crash when i flutter run?

Tags: android, windows, flutter

Am currently working on a Flutter project, First everything was working fine but now for some reason whenever i tried to flutter run my project to a usb-connected devices my window just blue screen crash on me.

Comment: You. should offer a minimal project to reproduce this.

Comment: does the issue occur for different windows pc/laptops? did you try the simulator?